# Js test function that does not return anything

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am using mocha and sinon. i have for example this function:

```
function doSomething(param) {

   if(param === 'something') { // do something }

}
```

How i can create test that check if the condition not true then the function does not do anything?

```
it('should do something if param equal something', function() {
   // this part i know
});

it('should not do anything if param not equal something', function() {
   // how to test this part?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always check if the function returns undefined. A function always returns something. When you don't return anything explicitly, it will return undefined.